# SAXException iso-8859-2

Tags: android, xml, character-encoding, sax, iso-8859-2

I have an XML file which starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>`. I read it the following way:

```
SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(is, handler);
```

where `is` is an InputStream and `handler` is some arbitrary handler.
Then I get this exception:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 41152, column 17: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Actually there is a degree sign at that position, enclosed in a CDATA like this:

```
<![CDATA[something °]]>
```

Using the charset iso-8859-2, the parser should accept almost any character, including this one. This seems not to be the case. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I'm doing all this on Android.

Weird: it seems that the parser completely ignores the encoding attribute. I converted the file to UTF-8 while leaving the header as is, and now my program can read it without error. Why is that??

(I'm making the InputStream like this: `new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))`, i.e. without a reader, so that cannot be the error.)

Comment: Are you sure the data is *actually* correctly encoded as ISO-8859-2?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) this character is encoded as B0 in ISO-8859-2. Is that the actual byte at that position in the file?

Comment: Yes, I opened it in Notepad++, it says "ANSI encoding", and I have a Hungarian Windows, so I'm sure.

Comment: Ensure the `°` is encoded as the byte `b0` when examined in a hex editor.

Comment: @szali: never trust any text editor to correctly "detect" encodings or to check if it's correct. Not even Notepad++ gets it right all the time.

Comment: Don't know if this is the case here, but java parsers are gnerally using the specified encoding, or system-default encoding if not specified, and not the encoding declared in file

Comment: @lechlukasz: that's the case if you manually try to read the text. The XML parsing APIs use the correct detection code and handle encodings correctly (unless you break them by manually creating a `Reader` with the wrong encoding and pass that in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the error by recognizing the encoding manually. I peeked the XML header and looked for the `encoding` attribute (if available), extracted as a String, created a Java `Charset` object from it by `Charset.forName()`, then made a Reader with the given encoding and an InputSource over that Reader like this:

```
String encoding;
Charset charset;
[...]
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
    inputSource.setEncoding(encoding);
    SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(inputSource, myHandler);
```

Unfortunately I still don't know why the encoding could not be recognized automatically by the parser.